# Why can't my unit attack within two hexes?

Tags: civilization-5

This is my situation:

[image: Shows a player attempting to attack in CIV and his opponent has the great wall]

I understand how terrain can slow movement. However, for the print screen below, I cannot work out why my elephant cannot attack the cavalry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your screenshot, it appears your opponent has built the [Great Wall](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Wall_%28Civ5%29).  You're crossing into his territory, and the effect of the Wall is that your movement will be penalized.

I'd be willing to bet that if you hovered over the hex just left of the enemy unit, your Elephant unit would path down and to the left towards it, rather than down and to the right, which would cross over into enemy territory and take a movement penalty.

The Great Wall is an excellent choice for a Civ who is planning for war, as it gives attacking units a serious disadvantage - marching on a city in this case is going to be a slow process, and it will give the defending city's siege and range units extra turns to decimate the attacking forces.

Comment: He does have the great wall. However, the edge of the grat wall is in the top right corner of the printscreen. Does having the great wall affect in side the territory or inside the great wall?

Comment: Yes, the wall is drawn over the boundaries of the Civ at the time it is built, but it effects any area within that Civ's borders, regardless of where the borders move afterwards.